# Show sql queries when load content

Tags: nodes, database

I'm working with the data from a Drupal 7 site that I have and I need to extract the data from a table with a relation to another table. The problem is that one of the tables is **Node** table and the other is **field_data_field...** that has a **target_id**.

The queries I have tried are not connecting  the data correctly between this tables. I know this because  when I go to the content page (http://example.com/ca/content/aalto-erick) the data is not the same.

Is there a way to display the SQL queries that executes the server when displays this content page?

PD: I put the url to show that the info is displaying in a content page.

Comment: Also show us what you tried and the query you have written for this

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) has a submodule called [Web Profiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/webprofiler). Once the Web Profiler module is enabled, there will be toolbar in the footer. The toolbar contains a DB inspection button signified by a DB "stack" with the number of queries performed and the time to perform them. Click the button will show you a profile of the DB queries made in the last request.

Comment: Important to note that Web Profiler only comes with the Devel's  8.x version and not with 7.x nor 6.x

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Devel module has "Display query log” settings, You can this or have another way to get this through by  hook_query_alter or hook_query_TAG_alter hooks. You can use this reference link.

[How To Print SQL String Using Devel Module](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-print-sql-string-using-devel-module/)